# Flexible Indices in Arrays in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I wanna know how to set unlimited indices (limit) to indices in an array in vB.NET
I usually have to specify the maximum number of items in each dimension of the array, but when I don't know how many (let's say it's an ID field), will be there, I don't want to waste data.

So I want instead of writing

```
Dim storage(0 To 1000, 0 To 3, 0 To 5) As String
```

to write something like this (where * means unlimited), keeping the other limits respectively as they are:

```
Dim storage(*, 0 To 3, 0 To 5) As String
```

So then I can add items like this:

```
storage(123456,3,5) = "abcdefgh"
```

Comment: "unlimited indices (limit)" - Do you want to be able to specify an upper bound to the array or not?

Comment: Look into `List` objects rather than arrays - You don't have to declare their size.

Comment: Have a `Dictionary(Of String, String(,))` instead.

Comment: StingyJack, no I don't want, and I want the array to get extended as I add values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't do that :)  Dynamically re-sizing arrays as necessary is unnecessarily confusing.  Multi-dimensional arrays are unnecessarily confusing too.  So dynamically re-sizing a multi-dimensional array is unnecessarily torturous.

When the size of the array is dynamic, don't use an array.  Use a `Collection`, instead, such as the `List(Of T)` class.  And rather than using multiple dimensions, make a custom class that defines the objects that the list contains, for instance:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property PhoneNumbers As New List(Of PhoneNumber) 
End Class

Public Class PhoneNumber
    Public Property Number As String
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

Then, you can define your dynamic list of people, like this:

```
Dim people As New List(Of Person)
```

And you can add any number of phone numbers to a person, like this:

```
Dim person As New Person()
Dim phone As New PhoneNumber()
phone.Number = "123-123-1234"
person.PhoneNumbers.Add(phone)

Dim phone2 = New PhoneNumber()
phone2.Number = "123-123-4567"
person.PhoneNumbers.Add(phone2)
```

And you can, similarly, add multiple people, like this:

```
Dim person2 As New Person()
' ...
people.Add(person)

Dim person2 As New Person()
' ...
people.Add(person2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggests, this is not the preferred solution, but to answer your question, you can use `ReDim Preserve` to increase the size of the first rank as needed:

```
If UBound(storage, 1) < currentIndex Then
    ReDim Preserve storage(currentIndex, 3, 5)
End If

storage(currentIndex, 3, 5) = "abcdefgh"
```